# FileInputStream Error

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I have this piece of code, just to try to write it to a file. But when I compile it, it doesn't display any errors, but text in my file is unreadable, some Unicode codes etc... I use eclipse IDE. What could be the reason for this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Hello world!";
    int i = 143141141;
    try
    {
        //create new file with an ObjectOutputStream
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

        //write something in a file
        oout.writeObject(s);
        oout.writeObject(i);
        //close the stream
        oout.close();

        //create an ObjectInputStream for the file we created before
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                                                new FileInputStream("test.txt"));
        //read and print what we wrote before
        System.out.println("" + (String) ois.readObject());
        System.out.println("" + ois.readObject());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you think object representations are readable?

Comment: There is no text file here. There a file of serialised objects. There is no reason to expect it to be human-readable. Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP ObjectOutputStream is converting object into stream of bytes. ObjectInputStream is converting it back into Object(String) in this case and its working as well.

Comment: Your code is fine, I don't see any issue, its printing expected values. The problem in your case could be of encoding, what's the encoding you see when you run: `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`

Answer (score 2):

With an `ObjectOutputStream`, you're using `Serialization` to write your objects to a file. Serialization is using an encoding system, and you use correctly an `ObjectInputStream` in your program to decode these objects. But you won't be able to read the information in the file created by the Serialization process.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream , it will write in Object code , which is not readable , and as well when u read from file , it will come up as an Object so again as an Object ,

Use BufferedReader or Writer to write String into file , which can be read

```
FileReader f=new FileReader(new File("test.txt"));
BufferedReader f1=new BufferedReader(f)
```

;

Comment: ObjectInputStream will also convert those stored bytes into Object

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to write text files, `ObjectOutputStream` writes binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Java ObjectOuputStream writes objects in a binary non human readable format which can be read only with ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me. If I understand it correctly when look at the contents of file by opening it in editor (say notepad or eclipse) you see characters stored as binary content in it. As you are using ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream the behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing values of your `String` and `Integer` objects but their object representations in binary format. That is called `object-serialization`. That is some how encoded to represent all the information associate with the `object` not only its `value` That is only displayed when decoded in the same way as we encoded them. So, normal `text editor` cannot display the information as you expected.

If you want to save the string representation only, use the classes such as `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It's working perfectly for me.  See the attached image. [image]

Try cleaning your workspace. If it doesn't work, try creating a new Java project and copy the same code posted here and try. It should work.

Comment: It was exactly with me too. but i guess due to some flushing problem his objects are not being written.

Comment: I would suggest trying cleaning workspace or trying same code in a new project.

Answer (score 0):

You're making the folly of writing the output string through an `ObjectOutputStream` which serializes the `String` and `Integer` objects in your code and saves the Object state along with the value of the object. This is the reason why you see encoded text when you open the file. The following excerpt sums up the values which are stored when an Object is serialized:

*The default serialization mechanism for an object **writes the class of the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient and non-static fields**. References to other objects (except in transient or static fields) cause those objects to be written also. Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written.*([`ObjectOutputStream`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/api/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.html))

*The writeObject method is responsible for writing the state of the object for its particular class so that the corresponding readObject method can restore it.*

*Primitive data, excluding serializable fields and externalizable data, is written to the ObjectOutputStream in block-data records. A block data record is composed of a header and data. The block data header consists of a marker and the number of bytes to follow the header.* ([`ObjectOutputStream javadoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html))

Answer (score -1):

The possible problem with your code is you are not flushing the output data. So that it might not get written to the output file.

Try the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "Hello world!";
    int i = 143141141;
    try
    {
        //create new file with an ObjectOutputStream
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

        //write something in a file
        oout.writeObject(s);
        oout.flush();
        oout.writeObject(i);
        oout.flush();        
        //close the stream
        out.close();
        oout.close();

        //create an ObjectInputStream for the file we created before
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.txt"));
        //read and print what we wrote before
        System.out.println("" + (String) ois.readObject());
        System.out.println("" + ois.readObject());
        ois.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And also if you want to read your written objects into the file then you can't because they are written as serialized objects. For textual operation with files you can consider BufferedReader or PrintWriter. see the following code.

```
public class WriteToFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String content = "This is the content to write into file";

            File file = new File("c:\\desktop\\filename.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After this you can open your text file and can see the written content in the human readable form and it is good practice to not to give "txt" formats when you are writing objects to the file. It's misleading.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but you are totally closing your streams in the wrong order.

Comment: @Sanchit : well, i don't see anything wrong here. After writing to the file i am closing FileOutputStream and then ObjectOutputStream. You can point the mistake if i am wrong.

Comment: You open out. Then open oout. Then close out. Then close oout. Looks wrong, seems wrong, probably works because of the oout.flush before the out.close but it probably works. Looks like that code is going to poop on you when you least expect it. I'd recommend closing streams in the order you open them.

Comment: @Sanchit : Well, if i don't close the out then also it will work fine because according to the documentation given at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close() it will release all the associated resource with it. You can have some real experience running the above code. just try it.

Comment: Interesting. So basically you don't need to do out.close() ever according to the documentation. Right? Anyawys, cool. I redact my statement.

Comment: @Sanchit : well, i didn't mean that. what i meant was closing anyone of them will close all its related resources also.